# Error getting authority in Ubuntu SDK Docker image

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

I want to run the Ubuntu SDK (Qt Creator variant) from a Docker image. It's working very nice, except when I try to use the emulator or a real phone/device. This requires to install a new *Kit* (armhf, i386) which fails with the following error inside a *Run Click* window.

```
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or directory 
---Click exited with errors, please check the output---
```

When I try to create a new Kit from a native Ubuntu, this action asks me to  insert the sudo-password. This does not happen with the Docker image (I tried to install `gksu` because of that, the docker user does not need a sudo-password though).

What is the problem here?

Here is the Dockerfile I created:

```
FROM ubuntu:15.04
MAINTAINER Name <email@example.com>

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN echo "deb http://mirror.skylink-datacenter.de/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted universe multiverse " > /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb-src http://mirror.skylink-datacenter.de/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted universe multiverse " >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb http://mirror.skylink-datacenter.de/ubuntu/ vivid-security main restricted universe multiverse " >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb http://mirror.skylink-datacenter.de/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted universe multiverse " >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb-src http://mirror.skylink-datacenter.de/ubuntu/ vivid-security main restricted universe multiverse " >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb-src http://mirror.skylink-datacenter.de/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted universe multiverse " >> /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -qqy software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:saiarcot895/myppa

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-fast

RUN apt-get update && apt-fast -y install \
    bash-completion \
    vim \
    dialog \
    gksu \
    build-essential \
    ubuntu-device-flash \
    phablet-tools \
    usbutils \
    ubuntu-sdk \
    ubuntu-emulator \
    x11-apps \
    cmake                                                                                                                                     

RUN export uid=1000 gid=1000 && \
    mkdir -p /home/dev && \
    echo "dev:x:${uid}:${gid}:dev,,,:/home/dev:/bin/bash" >> /etc/passwd && \
    echo "dev:x:${uid}:" >> /etc/group && \
    echo "dev ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/dev && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/dev && \
    chown ${uid}:${gid} -R /home/dev

USER dev
ENV HOME /home/dev
ENV DISPLAY :0

CMD ubuntu-sdk
```

The container is started with

```
XS=/tmp/.X11-unix && \
XA=/tmp/.docker.xauth && \
U=/dev/bus/usb && xauth nlist :0 | sed -e 's/^..../ffff/' | xauth -f $XA nmerge - && \
docker run --privileged -ti --rm -v $XS:$XS -v $XA:$XA -v $U:$U \
-v /home/dev/workspace/ubuntu-sdk:/home/dev -e XAUTHORITY=$XA dev/ubuntu-sdk:15.04
```

Native SDK `pstree` and `lsof` when the GUI requests the user password:

```
ubuntu-sdk,4267
  ├─pkexec,4480 env CLICK_NO_LOCAL_MIRROR=1 /usr/share/qtcreator/ubuntu/scripts/click_create_target armhf ubuntu-sdk-15.04 vivid click
  │   └─{gdbus},4481
  ├─{QProcessManager},4280
  ├─{QQmlThread},4292
  ├─{QQmlThread},4310
  ├─{QQmlThread},4317
  ├─{QQuickPixmapRea},4293
  ├─{QQuickPixmapRea},4316
  ├─{QQuickXmlQueryE},4318
  ├─{QThread},4289
  ├─{QXcbEventReader},4268
  ├─{Qt HTTP thread},4302
  ├─{Qt HTTP thread},4304
  ├─{Qt HTTP thread},4306
  ├─{Qt HTTP thread},4308
  ├─{Qt HTTP thread},4319
  ├─{Qt HTTP thread},4340
  ├─{Qt HTTP thread},4345
  ├─{Qt bearer threa},4291
  ├─{gdbus},4269
  ├─{gmain},4271
  ├─{ubuntu-sdk},4274
  ├─{ubuntu-sdk},4275
  ├─{ubuntu-sdk},4276
  ├─{ubuntu-sdk},4277
  ├─{ubuntu-sdk},4290
  ├─{ubuntu-sdk},4298
  ├─{ubuntu-sdk},4299
  ├─{ubuntu-sdk},4300
  └─{ubuntu-sdk},4301

$ sudo lsof -p 4480
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
       Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
pkexec  4480 root  cwd    DIR              253,1     4096 1584843 /home/dev
pkexec  4480 root  rtd    DIR              253,1     4096       2 /
pkexec  4480 root  txt    REG              253,1    23304  396702 /usr/bin/pkexec
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1    51736  267146 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.21.so
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1    47616  267156 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.21.so
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1    97224  267140 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.21.so
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1    35688  267142 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.21.so
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1    72232  267095 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.13.0
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1   924096  267091 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.0.2
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1   137400  267116 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1    31680  267201 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.21.so
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1   105328  267199 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.21.so
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1   138400  267203 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1   108920  267234 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1    14624  532751 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.4400.0
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1   158072  267213 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0.6.0
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1  1566696  532737 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.4400.0
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1   444344  267176 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.1
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1    31016  532634 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1    14592  267077 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.21.so
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1   109032  267050 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1.0.0
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1  1869392  267060 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.21.so
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1   142080  267193 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.21.so
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1    44280  533148 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpolkit-agent-1.so.0.0.0
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1   109928  533152 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpolkit-gobject-1.so.0.0.0
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1  1107040  267093 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4400.0
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1   334968  532765 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4400.0
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1    64048  267163 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0.83.1
pkexec  4480 root  mem    REG              253,1   154376  267032 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.21.so
pkexec  4480 root    0r  FIFO                0,9      0t0  183116 pipe
pkexec  4480 root    1w  FIFO                0,9      0t0  183117 pipe
pkexec  4480 root    2w  FIFO                0,9      0t0  183118 pipe
pkexec  4480 root    3u  0000               0,10        0    7679 anon_inode
pkexec  4480 root    4u  unix 0xffff880035e15500      0t0  184485 socket
pkexec  4480 root    5u  0000               0,10        0    7679 anon_inode
pkexec  4480 root    6u  0000               0,10        0    7679 anon_inode
```

Native SDK `pstree` and `lsof` of the Click Run:

```
$ pstree -p -l -a -h 4267
ubuntu-sdk,4267
  ├─click_create_ta,4480 /usr/share/qtcreator/ubuntu/scripts/click_create_target armhf ubuntu-sdk-15.04 vivid click
  │   └─click,4630 /usr/bin/click chroot -a armhf -f ubuntu-sdk-15.04 -n click create
  │       └─debootstrap,4640 /usr/sbin/debootstrap --arch amd64 --variant=buildd --components=main,restricted,universe,multiverse vivid /var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
  │           └─wget,4838 -q -O /var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/debootstrap.invalid_dists_vivid_universe_binary-amd64_Packages.bz2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2
  ├─{QProcessManager},4280
  ├─{QQmlThread},4292
  ├─{QQmlThread},4310
  ├─{QQmlThread},4317
  ├─{QQuickPixmapRea},4293
  ├─{QQuickPixmapRea},4316
  ├─{QQuickXmlQueryE},4318
  ├─{QThread},4289
  ├─{QXcbEventReader},4268
  ├─{Qt HTTP thread},4302
  ├─{Qt HTTP thread},4304
  ├─{Qt HTTP thread},4306
  ├─{Qt HTTP thread},4308
  ├─{Qt HTTP thread},4319
  ├─{Qt HTTP thread},4340
  ├─{Qt HTTP thread},4345
  ├─{Qt bearer threa},4291
  ├─{gdbus},4269
  ├─{gmain},4271
  ├─{ubuntu-sdk},4274
  ├─{ubuntu-sdk},4275
  ├─{ubuntu-sdk},4276
  ├─{ubuntu-sdk},4277
  ├─{ubuntu-sdk},4290
  ├─{ubuntu-sdk},4298
  ├─{ubuntu-sdk},4299
  ├─{ubuntu-sdk},4300
  └─{ubuntu-sdk},4301

$ sudo lsof -p 4480
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
       Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
click_cre 4480 root  cwd    DIR  253,1     4096 1441794 /root
click_cre 4480 root  rtd    DIR  253,1     4096       2 /
click_cre 4480 root  txt    REG  253,1  1029720  917511 /bin/bash
click_cre 4480 root  mem    REG  253,1  8720576  530587 /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
click_cre 4480 root  mem    REG  253,1  1869392  267060 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.21.so
click_cre 4480 root  mem    REG  253,1    14592  267077 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.21.so
click_cre 4480 root  mem    REG  253,1   167128  267217 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
click_cre 4480 root  mem    REG  253,1   154376  267032 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.21.so
click_cre 4480 root  mem    REG  253,1    26258  788593 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
click_cre 4480 root    0r  FIFO    0,9      0t0  183116 pipe
click_cre 4480 root    1w  FIFO    0,9      0t0  183117 pipe
click_cre 4480 root    2w  FIFO    0,9      0t0  183118 pipe
click_cre 4480 root  255r   REG  253,1     1381 1322872 /usr/share/qtcreator/ubuntu/scripts/click_create_target
```

Comment: I guess you lack some `-v ...` in the `docker run`, maybe some `lsof` in your host when you  Run Click will show what needs to be added

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It seems that `pkexec` (not `gksu`) is used and fails with the error `Refusing to render service to dead parents.` It tried to create a polkit policy to allow everything without a password, but that doesn't work. I added the output to the question.

Comment: see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/957641 if you use Rocko idea, does it work? (go inside your container with `docker exec -it container_id bash` modify, commit and run the modified image)

Comment: `Cannot run program gnome-system-log: No such file or directory` What idea do you mean? Did you mean something else? Thanks!
EDIT: I installed it, same error: `$ pkexec gnome-system-log
Refusing to render service to dead parents.`

Comment: talked about `For a workaround, "sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/gnome-system-log.desktop", remove the word pkexec from the EXEC= line, and save the changes.` in the link

Comment: It doesn't work, still the same error. I don't start it from the .desktop file anyway. Maybe I could get pkexec to work in Docker?

Comment: noticed http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203136/how-do-i-run-gui-applications-as-root-by-using-pkexec and https://www.ejabberd.im/node/24896

Comment: Thanks again. The command works when running with sudo instead of pkexec. I tried to replace pkexec with a sudo wrapper-script, which didn't work though.